# How do you use environment variables in Tup run statements?

Tags: tup

I'm trying to run a file given an environment variable to generate some environment-specific rules.

However, Tup doesn't allow for environment variables to be used in Tupfiles directly (you can send them through to child processes using the `export` keyword but you can't use them in `run` statements).

How can I use an environment variable in a `run` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using the `export` keyword to pass the environment variable through to a child process (bash, in this case), and then using the child process' ability to access environment variables to then run whatever script you want.

To do this, create a helper script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# bootstrap-script.sh
"${!1}/$2"
```

which takes the first argument passed to it, *resolves it* as a variable name, and then performs a replacement (where as the second argument is a direct replacement), and then run it from your Tupfile by using:

```
# Tupfile
export SCRIPT_DIR
run ./bootstrap-script.sh SCRIPT_DIR my_script.py
```

The above passes through `SCRIPT_DIR` to the previously mentioned bootstrap script, along with a target script or program to run (in order to generate rules using Tup's `run` keyword).

Comment: This is absurdly complicated. Hard to believe there is no simpler way...

Comment: @Szczepan agreed.